# How do you do this in a calculated property

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

In my MVC 3 app I have the following

```
public class SalesPerson
 {
      public SalesPerson()
    {
        this.SalesOrders = new HashSet<SalesOrder>();
        this.Ups = new HashSet<Up>();
    }

    public int SalesPersonId { get; set; }
    public int StoreId { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }

 public string StoreAndCode
    {
         get 
         {
              return Store.Code + ", " + Store;
         }
    }
```

I am assuming that I have to instantiate the store in the return statement in order to actually get the code and name for the return? How would I write this so I can expose this in the corresponding view?

Comment: Are you asking how to expose your StoreAndCode property to your MVC view?

Comment: Or are you asking how to load `Store` from a database?

Comment: Sorry that question was a bit ambiguous! I was trying to create a calculated propery (Store and code) off of the Store Store property. I assume I have to instantiate store somehow in order to be able to crab the code and name in order to return it? As it stands now, I'm getting a NullReferenceException because it was me to create a new store object.

Comment: If you're using Code First, you can make the Store property virtual and EF will use lazy loading to load up the Store.  Then you can just set the property and save the SalesPerson object and EF will map it.  Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Ah....I forgot to set it to virtual.. Yup that's it..Seems like it is always the small details! :)

Comment: I have no clue how to mark this answered. :(

Comment: I created an answer for you.  =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your property to virtual.

```
public class SalesPerson
{
    ...
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
}
```